# In <input type='text'> and <textarea>, drag-selecting text outside the box throws selection to end of text

Tags: html, pointers, text, mouse, selection

[image]

Is there some CSS to control selection behavior? In general I don't see this problem online, selecting to the left keeps the text on the left, but not in my case.

I have tried `setPointerCapture()` and `releasePointerCapture()` in `pointerdown` and `pointerup` respectively, but to no effect.

How can the textbox effectively capture the pointer for the duration of mouse selection, to prevent this jumping?

Here is my code:

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
textbox.addEventListener('pointerdown', e => {
    //this.textbox.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId); // tried this but it doesn't work
    if (e.button == 1) // I use MMB for panning, this is irrelevant to the problem
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});

textbox.addEventListener('pointermove', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

textbox.addEventListener('pointerup', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //if (this.textbox.hasPointerCapture(e.pointerId))
    //    this.textbox.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
});
```

```css
.textControlTextarea {
    color: var(--figma-color-text);

    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 11;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 5000;

    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;

    resize: none;
    cursor: auto;

    border-radius: 0.5px;
}


.textControlTextarea:focus {
    outline: 2px solid var(--figma-color-bg-brand);
}


.textControlTextarea:focus::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}


.textControlTextarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: transparent;
    width: 6px;
}


.textControlTextarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0;
}


.textControlTextarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #fff4;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea class="textControlTextarea" id="textbox"></textarea>
</div>
```

(This is a Figma plugin btw, but I figure that makes no difference as web is web)

Comment: Can you show your html/css code ?

Comment: Of course. These are the events I assign to the textarea: https://pastecode.io/s/ju9c8pof, and this is its CSS: https://pastecode.io/s/cdgjkrkp. I'm not really doing anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to add your code in your post but the HTML part is missing. You can [edit] the snippet to make it works. I'm not sure if it's with all devices or not

Comment: Wtf did stackoverflow just edit my post? I definitely did not write "Here is my code"... Anyway, the div is created at runtime by JS code so there's no HTML to post, I create it with `document.createElement('textarea')`, and set spellcheck to false. ‍♂️

Comment: You can see "Edited 1 hour ago by Elikill58" I edited myself as I have enough reputation